# Caching packets inside the network

Tags: routing

**Problem**:

Let's say I have a network with 10 users or more, all of them want to watch the same video or surf the same web page.

**Goal**

I'm looking for a way to **cache** the incoming packets inside private storage or anything similar.

Is this kind of thing could be achievable?

Comment: Caching can only be done on the application level which is explicitly off-topic here. For a business network, your question may be suitable for [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't perform cache at the TCP/IP level. This simply not how it works.

(it's a poor parallel, but it's little bit like asking if you could cache phone calls because several people will use the same words).

Actually, re-sending a previous packet is a kind of attack and there's mechanisms in the network stack to prevent this.

You can cache some HTTP content, this is usually done on an HTTP proxy, but HTTTP is off-topic here. (and there's less and less content that you can cache, web pages tend to have more and more dynamic content that cannot be cached).

Comment: Thank you for your time, I will look more for HTTP caching.